# Android - Is it possible to specify a minimum heap size requirement?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, heap-memory, heap-size

Is it possible (maybe within the app's manifest file or within the Google Play listing) to specify the minimum VM heap size that is required for a device to run an app?

I have set `android:largeHeap="true"` in the `<application>` tag of my manifest, but I would like it for my app to be unavailable to devices that can't provide a heap size of at least 64MB.

The prompt for this question is that we got a bad review from a user (due to OOM) with a 32MB heap and (until we can hopefully get our app's heap usage down below that level) that we would like to limit our app to devices with 64MB+ heaps.

I presume this approach would be OK as, similarly, our app is already unavailable to devices that are below API 14.

NB - I have looked in the [docs for the manifest's application tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) and the only mention of heap is the aforementioned largeHeap attribute.

Comment: I don't recall there being an option for that, though it would be a good idea. Note that you can detect your heap limit via `ActivityManager` and `getLargemMemoryClass()`, so if you wanted, you could warn users on first run of your app if their device is underpowered.

Comment: I've been looking for a list of heap sizes for recent phones for years, just to know whats out there. i found a link from this site to a list from around 2012, useless now. my game app needs 225, for high def images. i would rather limit it to newer devices than dumb down the resolution for the cheap devices. my only solution so far is to similarly set the minimum API to a high version.